# Android phone is silent on maxed out volume

Tags: java, android, volume

first post from me on SO, so here we go: I'm developing an app that communicates with accessory via audio jack. To be reliable the signals volume has to be maxed out. I use the media channel on an `AudioTrack` for playback. To set the volume I'm using the following code, recommended in several places, including SO:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

The to me rather surprising result: no sound at all. But, if I would, after this section has been executed, lower the volume manually on the phone (tested and confirmed on S+, S2, S3 and Nexus) it suddenly cranks up to max. Not on the slider, but on the actual volume. It gets worse with every repetetive execution of the app. Before execution everythings fine, 0 is silent and 15 is loud.
1st run: 15 is silent, 14 is max.
2nd run: 15 is silent, 14 is half, 13 is max.
...
Even worse: this behaviour is system persistent. After killing the app and listening to mp3's there's no sound when manually setting max volume with the volume rocker.

I replaced the `getStreamMaxVolume` (which seems to always return 15, several places state that the volume range is from 0-15, I haven't found proof for this) by static value 14 and at least there's sound now after startup, but my customer won't be too happy if my app alters his volume sliders behaviour, I fear.

I've heard/read about another method which can alter the volume relative to the users settings, so if he runs the phone at 50% volume, the method will control the volume between 0-50%, but I need the absolute max volume.

Oh, for complete records the AudioTracks init-phase:

```
mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mSampleRate /* 44100 */, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, 5000, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

And the playback (`mBAWholePeriod` is a Byte-Array):

```
mAudioTrack.write(mBAWholePeriod, 0, mBAWholePeriod.length);
```

So, I'd really appreciate if anyone would answer me despite my non-existant reputation!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option is to use MediaPlayer to play back to the audio.  Volume is a float between 0.0 (silent) and 1.0 (max).  Android use to all you to set large volumes, but that is a bug.  Use MediaPlayer.setVolume( 1.0f, 1.0f ).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)

By using the AudioManager you are tweaking the volume of phone as if you literally put your finger on the switch and bumped it up.  So yes that is why its persistent even after killing the application.  You might consider telling the user to make sure their volume is cranked up to the max instead of doing it for them.  You can use the AudioManager to interrogate what level its at then inform the user you need max volume.  Then they can turn it up.  Or you can save off his setting and restore it later after your app goes quiet, etc.

Comment: Well, I'll stick with reading out current volume levels and suggesting to raise the volume if necessary. Though I'm having a tough time to accept that there's no error in my implementation and AudioTrack is bugged. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The AudioTrack class has a setStereoVolume( left, right ) call that operates completely independent of the system's volume settings.  It appears that is set on the specific track itself.

Seeing how you instantiate with Mono rather than Stereo sound in your track, I don't know if you'd end up with the desired results.